# Body Paint Scratch Repair

Tags: suzuki, paint-scratches

I have a copper 2011 Suzuki SX4 Crossover.  I bought it in May, and it is already scratched, in one spot all the way through to the metal.  I'd like to get some kind of touch-up or clear coat on it to prevent rust, but I'm at a loss to find a good product.  Can anyone recommend something that's easy to apply?  I'm useless when it comes to auto repair, so preferably I would like to fine that can be easily brushed on and dries in a few minutes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local Suzuki dealer should be able to supply the touch-up paint that you need.

Comment: My "local" Suzuki dealer is an almost 2 hour drive from my home.  It's hard to justify eating up most of my Saturday to fix such a little thing.  The affected area is not immediately visible, so all I really need is just a little clear coat.  (Maybe I just answered my own question.)

Comment: You don't have to drive there.  Just grab the paint code off your door sill, give them a call and have them ship you one of the nifty little touch-up paint bottles.  :-)

Comment: Either that or grab said paint code and check if any of the local auto parts stores or paint suppliers are able to provide you with a touch up bottle. Just keep in mind that it's pretty much impossible to get an invisible repair with touch-up paint, especially if the paint is metallic or mica.

Comment: The Suzuki dealer I called informed me that they do not carry touch-up paint.  This seemed odd to me, but they referred me to http://www.colorrite.com/ for touch-up paint, which when I went through their Pain Wizard linked me to http://www.expresspaint.com/.  I ordered the recommended touch-up paint pen, and when all was said and done it matched very well with the existing paint.